# Using Airbnb's "react-with-styles" in React Native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, react-with-styles

Does anyone have a clear example of how to use [react-with-styles](https://github.com/airbnb/react-with-styles) (with [react-with-styles-interface-react-native](https://github.com/airbnb/react-with-styles-interface-react-native)) inside a React Native project? The only example provided in their GitHub page is for a React project.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Solution moved from question to answer</sub>

> The React example is working on React Native too, but what they're not mentioning is that you also need to add a dependency on [babel-preset-airbnb](https://github.com/airbnb/babel-preset-airbnb) for it to work.